# Cannot get length of a list

Tags: javascript, appcelerator

Hay, i have the following list

```
var feedObjects = {
    0:[
        "url",
        "image"
    ],
    1:[
        "url",
        "image"
    ]
}
```

However when i try doing feedObjects.length it always returns null, any ideas?

Comment: It should return *undefined* because *feedObjects* does not have a length property.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have an `Object` (`{}` are the literal `Object` notation), **not** an `Array`, so there is no `length` property.

You will need to iterate over it with `for ( in )`, except this guarantees no ordering of the properties, unlike an `Array` (though in practice they generally come in the order defined).

Better still, swap `{ }` with `[ ]` and use a real `Array` (well as close as JavaScript's arrays are to real ones).

Comment: How would i solve this? How would i get the length of the array.

Answer (score 3):

You have declared an associative array, not an indexed array. Try this

```
var feedObjects = [
    [
        "url",
        "image"
    ],
    [
        "url",
        "image"
    ]
];
```

Comment: Thanks for this Tim, it helped me with my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your object doesn't have a length property or method-

you need to count its members.

```
var feedObjects={
    ["url","image"],["url","image"]
}
function count(){
    var counter= 0;
    for(var p in this){
        if(this.hasOwnProperty(p))++counter;
    }
    return counter;
}
count.call(feedObjects)
```

**returned value: (Number)=2**

or define an array:

```
var feedObjects=[ ["url","image"],["url","image"]];
```

**//feedObjects.length=2;**

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.size = function(obj) {
     var size = 0, key;
     for (key in obj) {
         if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
     }
     return size;
 };
alert(Object.size(feedObjects))
```